# 20 hour query from hell

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

i am running this query on a table that has half a million records with about 7 fields:

```
delete from qvalues where rid not in  
(
select min(rid) from qvalues
group by name,compound,rowid
having COUNT(*)>1)

and rid not in  (select min(rid) from qvalues

group by name,compound,rowid
having COUNT(*)=1);
```

why is it taking SO LONG?

what can i do to optimize it?

im running sql server 2008

Comment: Are you sure its 20 hours ? Before executing the query, make sure that there is no lock on the table...

Comment: Is there an index on the table?  Keys?  Schema?

Comment: @madh how do i check if there is a lock

Comment: Can't you replace the `rid not in (... >1) and rid not in (... =1)` by `rid not in (... >= 1)` ?

Comment: What is aim of this query please? Delete duplicates?

Comment: @Nicolas: No, combining them that way excludes one rid, the way he has it excludes 2.

Comment: What percentage of the 1/2M rows are you trying to clear out and how many indices are on the table. If you are deleting a large percentage and there are a few indices you may be better moving the data you want to keep into a new table and then truncating the original before moving the data you want to keep back.

Comment: @Jeff - No I think you've got yourself confused on this one. @Nicholas's simplification is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as considering batching and indexing you can also rewrite the query itself to remove the sub queries and be more efficient.

```
;WITH cte As
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, compound, rowid ORDER BY rid) AS RN
FROM qvalues
)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE RN > 1
```

How many duplicates per group will there be likely to be? If many it might be quicker to do an insert of the records to keep into a new table and then a drop and rename.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to look at the execution plan and see what's taking the longest. I'd start by reducing the two `not in` queries to one:

```
delete 
from qvalues 
where rid not in
(
    select min(rid)
    from qvalues
    group by name, compound, rowid
    having count(1) >= 1
)
```

You might also want to look into putting an index on `name`, `compound` and `rowid`

Comment: I also made this mistake which Jeff pointed out. This is not the same as the original query as this only excludes one rid.

Comment: @Jim - This is exactly the same as the original query. It does not only exclude one rid at all. The original query deletes duplicates on the basis of `name, compound, rowid` leaving the one intact with the minimum rid for that group. That is what the query in this answer and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555623/twenty-hour-query-from-persephones-nightmare/4556062#4556062) correctly do.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the actual data involved, I can just give some general advice: Run each of the subqueries individually.

Also, am I reading this wrong, or are you deleting all but 2 entries from this table (if rid is unique)?

Comment: In that case, why not just copy out the data you want to save, then delete the whole table, and re-add the data you copied out?

Comment: I like that idea (+1), the only thing to beware of are triggers, indexes, etc. on the original table that would need to be duplicated on the  new table.

Answer (score 1):

**1 - Use batching.**  This lets you resume, and gives you an idea of progress.  As an example:

```
DECLARE @MSG Varchar(max)

WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        DELETE TOP (100000) qvalues
        FROM qvalues WITH (TABLOCKX)
        <logic here>
        IF @@ROWCOUNT < 100000 BREAK        
        SET @Msg = 'Deleted another 10 Million'
        SET @Msg = @Msg + ' ' +CONVERT(varchar(20),GETDATE(),101)+' '+CONVERT(varchar(20),GETDATE(),108) 
        RAISERROR(@Msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
    END
```

Note that I also added a `WITH (TABLOCKX)` hint, which puts a table lock on and eliminates row-level locking.  It'll cause issues with concurrent reads but hopefully you don't have anything else querying that table while you are deleting.

**2 - Fix your logic**  This is impossible to write for you without a better idea of your table structure, but some options are:
- Materialize a table with the values you want to compare against and do a join.  If the delete is big enough you can make a clustered index on the temp table on the join field.  I've used this a lot with great success.
- If you expect to delete a large portion of the records, `SELECT INTO` a new table and drop the old one.  This is a minimally logged operation and runs really quickly on SQL Server 2008 compared to a delete, which needs to log the values for each row.
- Drop all your indexes but what you are using for selection and your clustered index.  Keeping a clustered index is normally OK for a delete of this type if it's a relevant cluster to the query.

Answer (score 0):

first thought:

```
delete from qvalues where rid not in  
(
select min(rid) from qvalues
group by name,compound,rowid
having COUNT(*)>1

UNION

select min(rid) from qvalues
group by name,compound,rowid
having COUNT(*)=1);
```

Maybe its also a good idea to ensure, that the sql-server knows, that you are doing a "uncorrelated subselect" (because "correlated subselects" take much longer):

```
delete from qvalues a where a.rid not in  
(
select min(b.rid) from qvalues b
group by b.name,b.compound,b.rowid
having COUNT(*)>1

UNION

select min(c.rid) from qvalues c
group by c.name,c.compound,c.rowid
having COUNT(*)=1);
```

and of course you should consider to use indexes (especially on rid, but also on name, compound, rowid)

My SQLs are not tested - I hope you get the idea of what I was trying to show.

PS: your sql requires a lot of calculations (especially the `HAVING` clauses), could you try to find another solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

What is your machines setup, do you have enough memory, where do you see the most utilisation while the query runs (CPU, Memory, Disk IO) ?